# Custom (generic) view path resolver for asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created the following generic controller:

```
public class ReadController<TEntity> : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GridData()
    {
        IEnumerable gridData = ReadFromDatabase<TEntity>();
        return View(gridData);
    }
}
```

Then I have created the custom controller factory in order to use it and configured routing so that it can resolve the url:
http://server.com/MyApp/Read/MyEntity/GridData into

```
ReadController<MyEntity>
```

instance.

Now I would like to be able to create custom view for any generic type.

So, when I create the:
~/Views/Read/MyEntity/GridData.cshtml it means that this way is preferable

If it doesn't exist, then the search in the default paths:
~/Views/Read/GridData.aspx
...
~/Views/Shared/GridData.vbhtml